# How to upload file stored in memory?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.8, pydub

Currently, I use the following code to save the file first and to upload it after that:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import requests

file1 = AudioSegment.from_ogg("file1.ogg")
file2 = AudioSegment.from_ogg("file2.ogg")
file3 = file1.overlay(file2, position=1000)
file3.export('/tmp/output.ogg', format='ogg')

files = {
    'file': ('output.ogg', open('/tmp/output.ogg', 'rb')),
}
response = requests.post('https://example.com', files=files)
```

Is there any way to upload the file without saving it?

Comment: According to the docs, you can use file descriptor instead of filename, so you can use io.BytesIO() like this:

`f = io.BytesIO()`
`file3.export(f, format='ogg')`
`files = {'file' : ('output.ogg', f)}`

Tell me if it works, I'll write answer for future readers.